# Temp tables on the current connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

if I do:

```
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
```

I will see all the temporary tables in the system, however that view does not have information about which connection/user each table belongs to.  I'm interested in finding only the tables I've created on my current connection.  Is there a way to do this?

thanks - e

p.s. yes, I could try reading each table listed with the notion that those that succeed should prove to be mine (on recent versions one can't read other connections' tables) but that is too costly an approach since there may be thousands of tables on the system

p.p.s. I did read [Is there a way to get a list of all current temporary tables in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075483/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-current-temporary-tables-in-sql-server) which asks the right question but did not get a good answer

Comment: If you've created the tables yourself, on your own connection, then why not just keep track of which tables you created yourself?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - You are always so pragmatic, com'on - it's a fun question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - because I cannot be guaranteed that I'm the only one creating tables e.g. code I call (and to which I may not have access) may create tables I have no knowledge of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't name your #temp tables with three consecutive underscores, this should only pick up your #temp tables. It won't, however, pick up your table variables, nor can you change this code somehow to pick the tables on someone else's connection - this only works because `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo')` can only return true for a table in your session.

```
SELECT 
  name = SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name)-1),
  t.[object_id]
FROM tempdb.sys.tables AS t
WHERE t.name LIKE '#%[_][_][_]%'
AND t.[object_id] = 
  OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name)-1));
```

You might also be interested in space used by each of these tables (at least for the heap or clustered index), e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    name = SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name)-1),
    t.[object_id], 
    p.used_page_count, 
    p.row_count
FROM tempdb.sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS p
ON t.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
WHERE t.name LIKE '#%[_][_][_]%'
AND p.index_id IN (0,1)
AND t.[object_id] = 
    OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name)-1));
```

You could extend that to show total space for all indexes. I didn't bother aggregating per partition since these are #temp tables.

Comment: @Hogan because `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#foo')` will only return a non-null value if *you* have created a #temp table named `#foo`. If you create that table in a different window, `OBJECT_ID` can't resolve it. I am not 100% clear on how SQL Server keeps track of which #temp table belongs to which session, as that information is certainly not exposed, but it does keep track.

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to post if that was what you were relying on based on my tests.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - it's a clever solution but I came to ask because I was unhappy with the requirement that names don't include 3 underscores, which one can't be guaranteed.  I've also see temp tables named like `#29AFBDD0` (though I'm not sure quite how these come into existence) which would rework the logic.  Honestly I can't believe there isn't a demangling function! something like `select object_name_base(name) from tempdb.sys.tables)`

Comment: @ekkis a #temp table will have several dozen underscores in its name (actually #foo will have 112 - it is a function of 128 - 12 - the length of the name you give it). If you really want to name your #temp tables with three underscores (why?), you can change my script to look for 10, or 15. But I think that requirement is a little ridiculous. #29AFBDD0 is a table variable, and I don't know of any way to resolve that to a name or to your session.

Comment: @ekkis and by the way, I agree with you, there should be a way to map temp tables to a session. Please vote and comment here: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/285110/dmv-to-map-temp-table-session-id oh and here too: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/285113/allow-admins-to-drop-temp-tables-for-other-spids

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks for the links, I've upvoted and posted on both

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I've taken your lead and made the suggestion to M$.  You can upvote me at: http://goo.gl/JRS7m

Comment: this solution suffers in situations where the tempdb catalogue is locked.  I can do a 'from sys.tables with (nolock)' but, very much unfortunately, the 'object_id()' does a regular select and blocks.  grr...

Comment: Yeah several of the metadata functions are unable to respect certain isolations levels. It'd be great if there werean exception for temp tables, since they're the only ones we don't have workarounds for...

Answer (score 3):

```
select * 
from tempdb.sys.objects
where object_id('tempdb.dbo.' + name, 'U') is not null 
  AND name LIKE '#%'
```

Would tell you all the tables in tempdb beginning with # that you can access, but Aaron's script just blew me out of the water haha

Comment: indeed! his solution is very clever

Comment: I'm still working on getting a single upvote so I can comment on other people's questions lol

Comment: @Aushin well this query actually returns my #temp table and all permanent tables in tempdb (obviously some of those might belong to me, but not all of them).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess I meant "all the tables in tempdb that you can potentially access, if you had proper permissions".

Comment: Well the question asks specifically for temp tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand True, I've edited it to make sure the table starts with #.

Comment: If the edit with `#` is enough to constrain it, this actually seems like a cleaner/simpler solution than Aaron’s ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To find out the name of the user who create the object you just need to check for the schema ID and cross reference with the Schemas table

```
Select sch.name as 'User Owner' from tempdb.sys.tables TBL
join tempdb.sys.schemas SCH on TBL.schema_id = SCH.schema_id
where TBL.name like '#tmp_Foo%'
```