# T-SQL - Where is #tempimport?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a legacy db from an application that is no longer supported.  I'm trying to deconstruct a stored procedure to make a modification, but I can't figure out where #tempimport is located.  I've searched high and low through the schema, but I'm not finding anything close.  This is how it's used:

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @saleid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
 SELECT TOP 1 @saleid = [sale_id] FROM #tempimport;
```

Is this a T-SQL specific thing, or can I actually find the data in this table somewhere?

Comment: Is there a procedure that calls the one you are trying to evaluate? You could try something like redgate's sql search to find where it is being created.

Answer (score 1):

Tables that are prefixed with a `#` are temporary tables that are created in the `tempdb` system database.

Answer (score 1):

Tables with the `#` preceding the name are temporary tables.

You can find them in the `tempdb` database under `System Databases`

Answer (score 0):

- try to find code of this table creation in you DB schema

```
select * from information_schema.routines
where object_definition(object_id(routine_name)) like '%#tempimport%'
```

- try find #tempimport in schemas of neighboring DBs
- try find #tempimport in your application sources if exists.
- try to profile(SQL Profiler tool) your application and search #tempimport here.

Additional

- #tempimport can be created by any connected application. Not only from your DB runnable code
- you can research deeper and try to monitoring the moment of #tempimport creation. Example

```
select left(name, charindex('_',name)-1) 
from tempdb..sysobjects
where charindex('_',name) > 0 and
xtype = 'u' and not object_id('tempdb..'+name) is null
and left(name, charindex('_',name)-1)  = '#tempimport'
```

source: [Is there a way to get a list of all current temporary tables in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075483/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-current-temporary-tables-in-sql-server)