# Temporary tables used in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the count of how many `temporary` tables are used in a `stored procedure`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mabe this post is helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075483/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-all-current-temporary-tables-in-sql-server

Comment: just search for `#` in you stored procedure.

Comment: I wanted through a query to search, which includes 3000 lines of code in a SP.

Comment: @RohitKumar : That's not a good idea. Same temp table might used multiple times. For example, Create, alter, truncate, drop ....... with same temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to make this work for you:

1. Get the text of the stored proc from `Information_Schema.Routines` from the routine_definition column

`Declare @Def VarChar(Max) = ''
Select @Def = @Def + Routine_Definition 
From Information_Schema.Routines`

2. Split text of the routine by white space (one word on each row)

Read this great answer:

[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

3. Count / Display all distinct words that start with #

**Afterthought 1:**

Now if you have `[#One Two Three]` and `[#One Two Three Four]` it will show up as `#One` only, so you would have to use some TSQL trickery to strip spaces between square brackets.

**Afterthought 2:**

Will you have to distinguish between `#Temp` and `##Temp` tables?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you want to do this but the following query might help.

This just counts the number of hashes that appear a stored procedures definition which is stored in the system view 'sys.sql_modules'.

```
SELECT
    LEN(m.[definition]) - 
    LEN(REPLACE(m.[definition],'#','')) AS 'CountOf#Characters'
FROM
    sys.sql_modules m
    JOIN sys.procedures p
        ON m.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
WHERE
    p.[name] = 'Testing' -- <<the name of your stored procedure
```

Of course this assumes the procedure only contains CREATE TABLE #Table1 style statements. If hashes are used to drop the tables or even used in code comments you will need to take this into consideration with wrapping replace functions.